# How do I make it so that the spread comes up on one click?

Tags: unity

In Ubuntu 12.10, if I have multiple windows of an app, the first click on an icon brings the app window that is focused into view, and only the second click brings up what Ubuntu calls the spread here: http://design.canonical.com/2012/03/task-switching-in-ubuntu-and-a-introduction-to-the-spread/

As someone who just switched to Ubuntu from Windows XP, which effectively gives me the spread in one click, I find this slightly annoying.  Is there a way to change the preferences so that the spread comes up on the first click, not the second?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you'll get answers with more possibilities, but I can tell you that for the official Unity releases, the answer is no.  There's no such preference.  At least exposed in the UI.  I don't know of anything that could be changed through gsettings, either.  But perhaps it's escaped me.

There are a few third-party apps available from PPAs that allow for tweaking Unity more. My Unity, Ubuntu Tweak, and I believe others.  It's possible someone like that has coded this, too.  I can't remember more right now, so sorry that's all I can offer.